# Tomcat 7 instance doesn't start : usage catalina.sh

Tags: linux, tomcat, multiple-instances

i try to install tomcat7 instance on CENTOS7.

I wrote this script in my instance folder (routine):

```
export CATALINA_HOME=/usr/local/tomcat7
export CATALINA_BASE=/opt/tc7-instances/test/tomcat7
export JRE_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_60/jre/bin/java
cd $CATALINA_HOME/bin
./startup.sh
```

But when i run it, i get this message :

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /opt/tc7-instances/test/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/local/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /opt/tc7-instances/test/tomcat7/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_60/jre/bin/java
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/local/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/tc7-instances/test/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Usage: catalina.sh ( commands ... )
commands:
debug             Start Catalina in a debugger
debug -security   Debug Catalina with a security manager
jpda start        Start Catalina under JPDA debugger
run               Start Catalina in the current window
run -security     Start in the current window with security manager
start             Start Catalina in a separate window
start -security   Start in a separate window with security manager
stop              Stop Catalina, waiting up to 5 seconds for the process to end
stop n            Stop Catalina, waiting up to n seconds for the process to end
stop -force       Stop Catalina, wait up to 5 seconds and then use kill -KILL if still running
stop n -force     Stop Catalina, wait up to n seconds and then use kill -KILL if still running
configtest        Run a basic syntax check on server.xml - check exit code for result
version           What version of tomcat are you running?
Note: Waiting for the process to end and use of the -force option require that $CATALINA_PID is defined
```

However I have follow instructions : https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/RUNNING.txt 
And i have updated instance xml files as follow :
http://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/install-tomcat-8-centos-7/

In my script, if i change ./startup.sh with ./catalina.sh start, i get the same issue..

I don't understand what is the problem

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have confused $ and % for environment variable expansion. Try this:

```
set JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/opt/tc7-instances/test/tomcat7/endorsed"
set JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/tc7-instances/test/tomcat7/temp"
set JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager"
set JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/tc7-instances/test/tomcat7/conf/logging.properties"
set JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dprop_locator=/opt/tc7-instances/test/conf/database.properties"
set JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dlog4j_locator=/opt/tc7-instances/test/conf/log4j.properties"
set JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcsd.env=dev"
set JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xms128m"
set JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xmx1024m"
set JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:PermSize=64m"
set JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:MaxPermSize=256m"
set JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"
```

Comment: exact ! it doesn't work with : set JAVA_OPTS.....but it works with : JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS...."

Comment: Excellent. I have updated the answer accordingly. Are you still having issues getting Tomcat up and going?

Answer (score 0):

So,

after reading this post : http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2032330

i think the issue comes from my setenv.sh located in bin folder of my instance.

setenv.sh :

```
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/opt/tc7-instances/test/tomcat7/endorsed
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/tc7-instances/test/tomcat7/temp
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/tc7-instances/test/tomcat7/conf/logging.properties
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dprop_locator=/opt/tc7-instances/test/conf/database.properties
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dlog4j_locator=/opt/tc7-instances/test/conf/log4j.properties
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dcsd.env=dev
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xms128m
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xmx1024m
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -XX:PermSize=64m
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

I'm going to comment the differents commands before running the main script in order to isolate the one that generate the issue